# condition for having a positive solution to a linear equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, polytopes

Let $Y$ be a member of $\mathbb{R}^m$. 
I need a necessary and sufficient condition on a $n\times m$ binary matrix $A$ for having a solution to the linear equation:
$$AX=Y$$
Such that $X_i\geq 0$, $\forall i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.

Do you know a necessary and sufficient condition for unicity of this "positive" solution?

Comment: Obviously not sufficient, but necessary condition is that $Y$ is a non-negative vector and not a general $\mathbb{R}^m$ vector.

Answer (score 0):

check M-matrices:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix

If $A$ is an invertible M-matrix, then $A^{-1}$ has non-negative entries. That is, if $y\ge 0$, then the solution $x$ to $Ax=y$ is $x\ge0$.

Comment: The problem with M-matrices is that they are defined as a subset of Z-matrices (matrices with non-positive off-diagonal entries). Binary matrices (except in very special cases) are not Z-matrices and hence not M-matrices.

Comment: missed the binary part.